# How can I compile, install and run the tools inside kernel/tools?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

There are some tools in side the kernel,

> `<kernel source root directory>/tools`

perf is one of them.

In ubuntu I think the tools inside this folder is available as package linux-tools

How can I compile it form source and install it and run it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

what's wrong with the following?

```
make -C <kernel source root directory>/tools/perf
```

Comment: `make 0=/path/to/build/dir -C <kernel source root directory>/tools/perf`

Comment: That builds the tools and allows me to use those but how to build a similar package as official `linux-tools` deb?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen the build-instructions for all official deb packages are [available online](https://sources.debian.org/src/linux-tools/3.16.56-1/debian/)

Comment: @umläute I mean, is it possible to build `linux-tools` deb package from vanilla kernel sources without applying extra patches or copying `debian` directories around similar to using distribution supported `make-kpkg` command to build vanilla kernel sources?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen, I think it is possible. Check my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/741358/202924).

Comment: @cojocar Your solution doesn't match the requirement "without applying extra patches" but I guess it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Nowdays: `make -C tools/ perf_install prefix=/usr/`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to compile for a different architecture and this seems to work. 
I had hosttools from buildroot in the output/host/bin directory. Most people will have it there if using buildroot. I had to specify the LD and CC flag. 
So substitute  with appropriate path and  is the prefix for toolchain name.

```
make CC=<buildroot-dir>/output/host/bin/<arch>-gcc LD=<buildroot-dir>/output/host/bin/<arch>-ld -C tools/gpio/
```