# Building .deb package for Linux perf?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, make, perf

There is a convenient Linux kernel makefile target "make deb-pkg" to build kernel, modules, headers as .deb. Then I can install/remove via dpkg command.

However, for perf compilation, there is only build source package option. I wonder if there is a way to build perf as installable.deb as well?

Comment: Doesn't `make-kpkg` do this? `perf` is in the `linux-tools-X.XX` package.

Answer (score 3):

see the patch ["kbuild: Build linux-tools package with 'make deb-pkg'"](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2012/02/msg01009.html). Or latest 
 you could use this patch ["RFC: builddeb: add linux-tools package with perf"](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2015/04/msg00013.html)However, those patch was not integrated into kernel source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these [patches](https://kernel.hadret.com/patches/) and apply them to the vanilla linux kernel. These patches are more recent than what was posted above. This will build `linux-tools-*.deb` packages. I've recently tested on the following versions:

- `linux-5.17.3` and `linux-5.19.13`
- On `linux-6.2.8` version, because [libtraceevent was removed from the kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/213b760fbc69f2d6aed8f64f006a17869f0d8da4), you'll have to remove the `dpkg-shlibdeps $tools_dest/usr/bin/* $tools_dest/usr/lib64/traceevent/plugins/*` line from the patch.